# Azure Application Gateway Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have a service that is running at port 8090 and would like to expose this service over https via Azure Application Gateway where I have installed the required certificate.

Here is what I have done
1. Configured a listener in Application Gateway with Front end port as 443
2. Configured a Http Setting with port 8090

It did not work for me. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is off topic here. Please take a moment to read the [help] and migrate your question to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: @Philonoist did you get a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I use the step from here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-multisite-azureresourcemanager-powershell

1. Have public IP address for listener
2. Create "backend pools", where you can register web server IP address
3. Create "listener port", where you can create new http or https port
4. Create "HTTP Setting", where you can point to listener port at backend pools
5. Create "rule", where you can associate (3-listener) -> (2-backend pools) -> (4-http setting)
6. Monitor "backend health", you may need to create custom probe for specific page checking

Cheer!